# How to read file in Angular/Typescript

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I am working on App, basicly Wordle, and I need to read words from file. I was trying to do it like this:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
const words = fs.readFileSync('./words.txt', 'utf-8');
console.log(words);
```

I installed nodejs and run cmd:

`npm install --save-dev @types/node`

But when I compile a project a got an error: **"Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'"**

I was trying to fix it, but i didnt find right answer.

Comment: `fs` is a _Node_ API, Angular apps run in the _browser_: https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/differences-between-nodejs-and-the-browser/. You can probably just import the JSON and get it bundled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call a nodejs api from an Angular app.

The app is only build using NodeJS but it is run in the browser.

Comment: And is it possible to do it in Angular App somehow? Without NodeJS?

Comment: You'll have to load the json from the assets using the httpClient

Answer (score 0):

you can use FileReader API to implement the file reading thing.

Besides, please have a look at the link below to see the issue & solution visually: TestWise Replay | StackOverFlow QA - [How to read file in Angular/Typescript](https://dashboard.testwise.io/replays/sJQYpuUMBLC)

Answer (score 0):

`fs` is only available on Node. Some people say it. But you can read files with Angular, too with help from an `input` and `FileReader`.

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" (change)="onChange($event)" >

<pre>{{ fileOutput }}</pre>
```

**Code**

```
export class AppComponent {
  fileOutput;

  onChange(event) {
    var file = event.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      // The file's text will be printed here
      this.fileOutput = e.target.result;
    };

    reader.readAsText(file);
  }
}
```

Then you see the text of the file.

Comment: Is it possible to do it without input? Just path to file and it will return array.

Comment: No. You cannot access to files with the browser. By the way: You do not know which file you need to open without input. The user has the control. Browser is the "users place". Not the server side.